# Problem with normal after merging vertices

Tags: normals

[image: Processed object with strange normal?]

I was doing some editing on a clone of the object on the left. After some vertices merges, Knife intersect, face deleting etc... the resulted object looks strange...

[image: Objects in edit mode with normals showed]

Here you can see the normals are different so maybe that was the problem. I want to make the object on the right look like the one on the left, what should I do?

I am pretty new to Blender and 3D modeling in general.

Comment: you've shade smoothed your object, to undo, right click and Shade Flat

Comment: @moonboots Exactly the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy the per-face-corner normals of the original object, you can use a data transfer modifier after merging vertices:

[image]

Notice that I've disabled "evaluate in global space".  Presumably your two objects have identical faces in their own local spaces, but they have different global transforms.  I'm also doing this via nearest corner and best matching face normal, which should be the appropriate method for what you're demonstrating, but other methods are useful in other circumstances (topology, nearest face interpolated are others that I would use frequently.)

You should apply this modifier (from the modifier dropdown menu) if you don't want it to be calculated live.